# Accessing a multi-dimensional array through pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I know, a lot was told about it, yet I couldn't find an explicit reference to what I need.

I need to have a struct member which will point to a two-dimensional array. The array size isn't fixed, each instance of the struct will point to an array with a different size.

I thought about the following way:

```
struct towDimByPtr
{
    int NumRow;
    int NumCol;
    int* ptr2TwoDim; 
};
```

Then I'll have globals:

```
int arr1[30][90];
int arr2[20][10];

towDimByPtr towDim1;
towDimByPtr towDim2;
```

At init I'll do:

```
towDim1.ptr2TwoDim = arr1;
towDim1.NumRow = 30;
towDim1.NumCol = 90;
towDim2.ptr2TwoDim = arr2;
towDim2.NumRow = 20;
towDim2.NumCol = 10;
```

Finally when accessing an element I'll use:

```
towDim1[curr_row*NumCol + curr_col]
```

My question: Will this always work.

Comment: C and C++ are [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_major) languages, so as long as you keep to that it should work. But I wouldn't recommend using it, as it's quite obfuscating.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Thanks. Could you please provide a reference to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assignment will not work:

```
towDim1.ptr2TwoDim = arr1;
```

`arr1` decays into `int (*)[90]`, not `int *`. You must do this assignment using a pointer to the first element, as in:

```
towDim1.ptr2TwoDim = &arr1[0][0];
```

Or, equivalently,

```
towDim1.ptr2TwoDim = arr1[0];
```

The same applies to `towDim2.ptr2TwoDim = arr2;`.

Apart from that, as long as you ensure that `curr_row` and `curr_col` are not out of bounds, then yes, it will always work.

Comment: Thanks Filipe. Could you please provide a reference to the fact that multidimensional arrays are guaranteed to be stored this way?

Comment: @Subway Yes, you can see it on wikipedia page about C: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#Arrays

For a more formal reference, C90 seems to hold this on section F.2.5, "Array storage" (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjbdp/index.html). It says that "C arrays are stored in row-major order; the last subscript in a multidimensional array varies the fastest."

Comment: @Subway Just checked on C99 that this is on Section 6.5.2.1, 3rd paragraph: "[...] It follows from this that arrays are stored in row-major order (last subscript varies fastest)".